# Nodemailer google workspace works in Dev but in production the emails go to spam

Tags: node.js, email, heroku, gmail, nodemailer

I have a project that sends emails back to people which I deployed on heroku. The problem is that it works fine in dev but when it has been deployed emails go directly to the spam. What causes this? Do you need more information from my code to help me?

```
 const oAuth2Client = new OAuth2(
    MAILING_SERVICE_CLIENT_ID,
    MAILING_SERVICE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    OAUTH_PLAYGROUND
  );
  oAuth2Client.setCredentials({
    refresh_token: MAILING_SERVICE_REFRESH_TOKEN,
  });
  try{

    const  accessToken = await oAuth2Client.getAccessToken();
    
    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      service: "gmail",
      auth: {
        type: "OAuth2",
        user: SENDER_EMAIL_ADDRESS,
        clientId: MAILING_SERVICE_CLIENT_ID,
        clientSecret: MAILING_SERVICE_CLIENT_SECRET,
        refreshToken: MAILING_SERVICE_REFRESH_TOKEN,
        accessToken,
      },
    });
    await transporter.verify();
    await transporter.sendMail({ from, to, subject, html });
     

///


await sendEmail({
    to: SENDER_EMAIL_ADDRESS,
    subject: subject,
    html: content
});
await sendEmail({
    to: email,
    subject: subject,
    html: `Dear ${firstName},
    <p> Thank you for getting in touch

    </p>
    <p>Best Regards,</p>
    `
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a multiple reasons why this can happen in my case the DKIM of my email api wasn't set up correctly and another things too  you can find out the reason why it is not working by  using [www.mail-tester.com](http://www.mail-tester.com) to see the rating of your email and the reasons for it too.

Answer (score 0):

If you get something like this "This email has failed its domain's authentication requirements. It may be spoofed or improperly forwarded!".

No, it's nothing that you can do. You've probably emailed yourself with fake emails like
"test@yahoo.com", try using your real email.

Comment: Hey  :) This email has failed its domain's authentication requirements. It may be spoofed or improperly forwarded!" Where would this  message come up ? and  why would it not happen in dev? and I am using a real email too.

Comment: That message is coming up in my email when i was testing my email form,i used random email addresses so that's why my emails were going to spam.

Comment: Okay I think I found the answer anyway Ill post it as answered if it works

Comment: You can use https://www.mail-tester.com/  to see why you are getting the problems and work through it that way.